# Unity Sprite image isnt centered

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, sprite

I am trying to add a sprite to my 2D game. The box in blue shows the location of the sprite and the image of the bearded man shows where the sprite shows up. No matter what I do, i cant get that picture to center with the sprite.

[image]

My settings here

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the image has a `RectTransform` instead of a regular `Transform` suggests it's a child of a `Canvas`, but you're using a `SpriteRenderer` instead of an `Image`.
That may cause issues, but I don't know if that's the cause of your problem.

Have you tried setting the `z` value to 0? It's now close to -1, which may cause it to render further away or closer to the camera, causing the offset on your screen.

Comment: Thanks! That didn't quite fix it but was a necessary change (it should be a Transform and Sprite). I believe it might be because my `Texture2D` isnt the right size for my `Sprite`? Is that possible?